# Record through two microphones simultaneously

Tags: matlab, audio-recording

I want to use two different microphones to record together with only one laptop.
Because the line-in has two channels, left and right I want to use each one connecting to a microphone, but how to write the MATLAB code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of input channels can be specified when creating an `audiorecorder` object - see the Matlab documentation for `audiorecorder`

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for reply you late.

Answer (score 0):

also in `audiorecorder` you can set the device ID for each specific device

```
recobj1 = audiorecorder(44100,16,2,1)
recobj2 = audiorecorder(44100,16,2,2)
```

the last argument in the fn is the device ID.

Hope this helps!